# Find time to practice English

Tags: time, time-words

Is 'find time' a natural thing to say?

"No matter how busy I am, I need to find time to practice English."

"Even though you're a busy man, you should still find some free time to spend with the family."

Comment: Yes, find or *make* time.

Comment: I believe you can also say *However busy you are, find time for your family.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  "find time" is completely normal and natural.

A good idea to investigate this sort of expression is to use the internet and search for  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22find+time+to+practice+English%22.